Fetched API data is being cached Next.js 14.2.8
My application has an API that has dice roll function it works as intended when running in development mode but when I build for production the data in the first API call becomes cached and the data on the page is not updated when the API is called for a second time.
Dice roll function/API
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const diceRollCalc = (min: number, max: number): number => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  };

  const result = diceRollCalc(1, 6);

  const response = NextResponse.json(result);
  response.headers.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  return response;
}

This is the react component that fetches the API
'use client'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function diceRoll() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
              const response  = await fetch('/api/diceRoll', {
            cache: 'no-store',
            headers: {
              "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
              "Pragma": "no-cache",
              "Expires": "0",
              "CacheControl": "no-cache",
            }
        } );
      const data = await response.json();
      setData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleButtonClick = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/diceRoll');
    const data = await response.json();
    setData(data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data && <p>Result: {data}</p>}
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default diceRoll;

This is my page
import React from 'react';
import DiceRoll from './diceRollClient';

export default function page() {

  return (
    <div id='main'>
      <h1>Dice</h1>
      <DiceRoll/>
    </div>
  );
}

I apologise if this is trivial as I am still learning.
Here are the response headers in the API Request for Development mode and Production Build
Development Mode
Connection  keep-alive
Keep-Alive  timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
cache-control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-type    application/json
vary    RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch
Production Build
Connection  keep-alive
Keep-Alive  timeout=5
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
cache-control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-type    application/json
vary    RSC, Next-Router-State-Tree, Next-Router-Prefetch
x-nextjs-cache  HIT

let data = await fetch('https://api.vercel.app/blog', { cache: 'no-store' })

For more details checkout official documentation
